# How to add any of a type in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to make a type that has another type: eg I want to make a bas response like below:

```
type Response = {
data: 'type of (any) ---> I want this to have a set type of a type or class I' create,
errors: null,
loading: false
}
```

I want to then be able to use that above on a variable like

```
const ordersResponse: Response<IOrder> = {
loading: false,
errors: null,
data: 'should be an array of entities that follow the IOrder type or interface'
}
```

is there a way to do this in typescript?

Comment: make a class or interface defining the types of the props, see [docs](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures#all-members-must-conform-to-the-string-index-signature)

Comment: will `data` always be some array?

Comment: no @Thomas not always

Comment: Then it would be better to define the type for `data` as an array-type: `Response<IOrder[]>`. Because otherwise you need to define the type for `data` as `T | T[]`  *(as seen in the current answers)*  and that's unnecessary ambiguity. Just go with `type Response<T> = { data: T;  etc. }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you currently defined your `Response` type, `errors` can only take the value `null` and `loading` can only take the value `false`. You have to define them with proper types.

And to have a generic `data` type, you have to make your `Response` type a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```
interface Response<T> {
  data : T | T[],
  errors: Error[] | null,  //or whatever the type of your error is
  loading: boolean
}


const aResponse : Response<IOrder> = {
  data: [{orderid: 1, ...}],
  errors: null,
  loading: false
}
```

With this approach, when accessing your `data` property, you still will have to validate, whether it's an array or a single object

```
if (Array.isArray(aResponse.data)) {
  const orderids = aResponse.data.map(x => x.orderid);
} else {
  const orderid = aResponse.data.orderid;
}
```

If you can predetermine in your code, whether the response contains a single object or an array of objects, it might be better to define the type accordingly. Ie

```
interface Response<T> {
  data : T,
  errors: Error[] | null,  //or whatever the type of your error is
  loading: boolean
}


const singleResponse : Response<IOrder> = {
  data: {orderid: 1, ...},
  errors: null,
  loading: false
}

const arrayResponse: Response<IOrder[]> = {
  data: [{orderid: 1, ...}],
  errors: null,
  loading: false
}
```

Then you don't need typechecking your `data` property, because it's always clear whether it's an array or not.

Comment: when i try to push an element to a type that has response<Order[]> i get the error 'Argument of type Order is not assignable to parameter of type Order & Order[]'

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the code you are currently using ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `|`?

```
type Response<T> = {
  data: T | T[],
  errors: null,
  loading: false
}

interface IOrder {
  orderNo: number;
}

const ordersResponse: ResponseXyz<IOrder> = {
  loading: false,
  errors: null,
  data: [{ orderNo: 12345 }],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to achieve this. One way that you are trying using interface is:

Create two interfaces something like this:

```
interface IOrder{
    field1: string,
    field2: string[],
    field3:boolean
    }

interface Response {
data: IOrder,
errors: string,
loading: boolean
 }
```

Later in your class, you can use it like this:

```
ordersResponse: Response = {
               loading: false,
               errors: null,
               data: {
                   field1: "field1Value",
                   field2: ['element1', "element2"],
                   field3:false
               },
           }
```

As you are new to Typescript, FYI only - You can create those interfaces at same file, before class definition starts and use those in your class. OR if you want them in available throughout your code base, find out some common .ts file, create those interfaces there and then import those in your .ts file and use in your code.